# Guice injection based on a condition

Tags: java, web-services, architecture, inversion-of-control, guice

I'm quite new to IoC containers, and I'm planning to use one in a new project. It's not sure that I'm certainly going to need it, but there is a possibility that the architecture will grow, so it's nice to know that this can work.

The project is a web service built with Resteasy that has integration with Guice. I've set it up and it works. My question is how can I choose an implementation of an interface, since there can be several, based on a variable. For example, a user sent parameter. The obvious solution would be a large switch/case statement, but I'm hoping a container would help. I've looked up into assisted injects and guice factories, but I can't fit it in my problem.

Any advice would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapbinder Extension is exactly what you need: http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with guice, so can't help with specific to guice.

But the generic idea should be using factory. `Spring` offers factory bean, which can be used to initialize bean as we want.

I believe there should be something similar for `guice` too. Consider using that and should be a good practice.

---

A little googling took me to this page: [FactoryProvider](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryProvider.html) and I believe this is what you should be considering.